# How to avoid string corruption on formatting razor views

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio, razor, code-formatting

In Visual Studio Express For Web 2012 if razor view is formatted, formatter adds extra spaces to end
of javascript string. This causes invalid data to be passed.

Before formatting:

```
@if (!(Model.Entity is Palk) && Model.Entity.CanInsert && !Model.IsNew())
{
    <input type="button" id="add_grid_top" class='button' value='@I("Lisa")'
        title='@(I("Lisa dokument") + " (Ctrl+N)")'
        onclick="javascript:replaceTab( 'Detail?' +$.param({ _entity:'@Model.FormName',
_vmnr: @Model.Vmnr }))" />
}
```

After pressing Ctrl+K D :

```
@if (!(Model.Entity is Palk) && Model.Entity.CanInsert && !Model.IsNew())
{
    <input type="button" id="add_grid_top" class='button' value='@I("Lisa")'
        title='@(I("Lisa dokument") + " (Ctrl+N)")'
        onclick="javascript:replaceTab( 'Detail?' +$.param({ _entity:'@Model.FormName        ',
_vmnr: @Model.Vmnr    }))" />
}
```

Note that string

```
'@Model.FormName'
```

is formatted to

```
'@Model.FormName        '
```

This causes invalid data to be passed to controller.
How to disable such formatting ?

ASP.NET MVC3, C#, jquery and Microsoft Visual Studio Express For Web 2012 are used.

**Update**

I tried

Tools / Options / Text Editor / HTML / Tabs settings but problem persist.

In Tab window Indenting does not change behaviour.
If Keep tabs is selected, two tabs are inserted after FormName.
If Insert spaces is selected, 8 spaces are inserted to after FormName.

I unchecked also some options in formatting tab but this does not cause any changes.
How to fix this ?

[image: Visula Studio options]

Comment: Try Using braces: '@(Model.FormName)'

Comment: Tried but this is formatted to `'@(Model.FormName)        '` - trailing spaces are still added. So this does not resolve the issue.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Go into options and change tab to equal 4 spaces. I believe the tab character is your issue.

Comment: If you're right, then that would just give the OP 4 spaces at the end instead of eight. And who in their right mind has indentation set to eight characters? I'm not convinced of this.

Comment: @DavidH This setting was already. I updated question with additional info. How to fix this?

Comment: Hmmm, in that case I'm not sure that you can, unfortunately.